# Endless while loop and fscanf not assigning data to struct

Tags: c, file, struct, while-loop, scanf

As a school assignment im tasked to read a list of football matches, with the following syntax

`weekday date time hometeam - outteam hometeam goals - outteam goals #spectators`
an example of thsi could be

`FRI     18/07 18.30     FCN - FCV     3 - 2     3.349`

Which would make the following entry into my struct

```
struct match_data
{
    char match_day[4];
    int match_date_day;
    int match_date_month;
    char match_time[6];
    char match_home_team[4];
    char match_away_team[4];
    int match_home_goals;
    int match_away_goals;
    int match_spectators;
};
```

match_day: FRI

match_date_day: 18

match_date_month: 07

match_time: 18.30

match_home_team: FCN

match_away_team: FCV

match_home_goals: 3

match_away_goals: 2

match_spectators: 3.349

So the problems accour when i try to read the file

my while loop seems to go on forever, when i run the code as is (with printf to test wether data has been assigned)

```
int game_loader()
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file_pointer;

    file_pointer = fopen("superliga-2014-2015", "r");

    if(!file_pointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return -1;
    }

    struct match_data match[200];
    while(!feof(file_pointer))
    {
        fscanf(file_pointer, "%[^ ][^0-9]%d/%d %[^ ][^A-Z]%[^ ] - %[^ ][^0-9]%d - %d[^ ]%d[^\n]\n",
        match[i].match_day,         &match[i].match_date_day,   &match[i].match_date_month,
        match[i].match_time,        match[i].match_home_team,   match[i].match_away_team, &match[i].match_home_goals,   &match[i].match_away_goals, &match[i].match_spectators);

        printf("day %d: %s\n", i, match[i].match_day);
        i++;
    }

    printf("match day is: %s\n"
        "match date is: %d/%d"
        "match time is: %s"
        "match is between %s - %s"
        "Score was: %d - %d"
        "the amount of spectators was: %d",
        match[1].match_day,         match[1].match_date_day,    match[1].match_date_month,
        match[1].match_time,        match[1].match_home_team,   match[1].match_away_team,
        match[1].match_home_goals,  match[1].match_away_goals,       match[1].match_spectators);

    return 0;
}
```

not only does the loop never close, but furthermore the fscanf never assigns data to the variables

im thinking it's because i format the fscanf wrongfully when i try to move from `match_day` to `match_date_day` i tried using [^0-9] to skip the spaces in between the day and the date

Comment: What's the return value of `fscanf()`? *And why doesn't your code check it?*

Comment: fscanf returns the amount of elements succesfully matched and assigned, i have not quite gotten into the habbit of checking fscanf's yet, would adding another set of parathesis around it to add `if != 9` be correct? so that the line would be `if(fscanf(file_pointer,Syntax for formatted txt) != 9)`

Comment: Uhm, cat eyes? i assume by that you mean either noting or a white / blank space what would you mean by this? :-)

Comment: `int match_spectators;` --> `char match_spectators[16];` and `fscanf(file_pointer, "%[A-Z] %d/%d %[.0-9] %[A-Z] - %[A-Z] %d - %d %[^\n]\n",
        match[i].match_day,         &match[i].match_date_day,   &match[i].match_date_month,
        match[i].match_time,        match[i].match_home_team,   match[i].match_away_team, &match[i].match_home_goals,   &match[i].match_away_goals, match[i].match_spectators);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the functions you call for potential failure. *Especially* functions as *prone* to failure as `*scanf()`. That is a habit you *should* get into.

You're probably looking at a match failure, i.e. the input not matching your format string, which makes `*scanf()` return early *without advancing the position in the file*.

So you just keep trying (and failing) to read the same data over and over again.

Besides, if the `*scanf()` failed, the `*printf()` of `match_day` might invoke undefined behaviour (printing uninitialized values). ;-)

---

As for *why exactly* your `*scanf()` fails... I am quite sure you *cannot* have *multiple* `[...]` in *one* conversion specifier.

Comment: As was commented above im trying to implement a `if(/* my scan funktion */ != 9)` to check if the scanf was succesfull, would that be sufficient?

Comment: Just figured that out :-p

Comment: @Dream_Reaper: Generally speaking, if there is *any* chance that your input might not be as expected -- as basically *always* unless your software has written that datafile itself, and possibly even then -- the advice is to use `fgets()` to read a whole line into memory, and then parse the line in-memory using e.g. `strtol()`, `strtod()` etc.. `*scanf()` is a fickle beast.